# How to install Fluentd plugins on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, fluentd, efk

I have set up EFK on Kubernetes, currently I have access only to logs from logstash but wondering how can I install some plugins for Fluentd in order to get some logs from eg. NGINX which I use as a reverse proxy? Can someone please point me how exactly I can configure EFK on k8s and what are the best practices around it? On k8s I have eg. API service in Express JS.

Comment: Let's try this tutorial
https://blog.powerupcloud.com/kubernetes-pod-management-using-fluentd-as-a-sidecar-container-and-prestop-lifecycle-hook-part-iv-428b5f4f7fc7

Answer (score 1):

You will find this article interesting for the begging:[Kubernetes Logging and Monitoring: The Elasticsearch, Fluentd, and Kibana (EFK) Stack – Part 1: Fluentd Architecture and Configuration](https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-logging-and-monitoring-the-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-stack-part-1-fluentd-architecture-and-configuration/)

Also there are a lot of fluentd plugins for kubernetes here: https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all#stq=kubernetes&stp=1

Each plugin has installation instruction, for example [Kubernetes Logging with Fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd)

Also you may want to try [Fluent Bit](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging) is a lightweight and extensible Log Processor

Comment: [A hands-on EFK logging tutorial is here](https://katacoda.com/javajon/courses/kubernetes-observability/efk).